# sched_getcpu equivalent on iOS

Tags: ios, mach

I am look for a way to detect which core the current thread is running on, for performance optimization/debugging reasons. Android/Linux systems provide `sched_getcpu()` function and `getcpu` syscall, which returns index of the current logical processor.

Is there an equivalent of `sched_getcpu/getcpu` on iOS?